# Is it allowed to bring condoms in airplane?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I'm about to travel via Wizz Air and only have hand baggage. Can I bring condoms on board?

Comment: What exactly are you worried about? Is there a specific reason why you think you can't take condoms on board?

Comment: @drat Presumably the concern that you might try to use them during the flight ;)

Comment: If you are going to blow balloons with them in the cabin, then no. Else why would they refuse ?

Comment: @DumbCoder balloons are a problem in [train stations](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34695/why-are-balloons-prohibited-at-amsterdam-schiphol) but I don't see why they'd be a problem on planes.

Comment: sometimes I don't bring any other luggage

Comment: Not sharp, flammable nor liquid. You will be able to stay protected while joining Mile-High Club

Comment: Maybe concerned about being accused of being drug mule?

Comment: @drat There is an old but untrue urban legend that condoms somehow loose their effectiveness as a result of the in flight pressurization / de-pressurization.

Comment: Don't see why any airline would have a problem with them as long as they're A) unused, B) legal in both the departure and destination country.

Comment: My fiancé had his condoms confiscated today by TSA at ACK airport.

Comment: @MeaghanHogan interesting, did they give the reason?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, and [there are great articles online detailing travelling with condoms](http://learn.condomdepot.com/2014/03/14/travel-condoms-preparing-for-international-visits/).  They're not liquids, flammable or on any of the TSA unapproved lists, so you're totally fine to take them.  However, remember they're meant to be stored at room temperature as they are still medical devices you don't want to take risks with damaging them. Don't store them with sharp items in your carry-on (even pens etc).  If your laptop or phone gets really warm, it's best not to have them side-by-side either.

However, there are also stories of travellers being detained [because of the condoms in their luggage](http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/clay-nikiforuk/sexism-at-us-border_b_3112638.html), where they were accused of being working girls(!), so ... all things considered, it might be better to just get some at the destination.

Comment: As the old joke goes "Sir, why did you bring condoms? Now we're gonna have to do a full cavity search" -> "my plan is working~"

Comment: Note that Wizz Air doesn't fly anywhere near the TSA.