# Can I take balloons on a flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, hand-luggage, fragile-luggage

Mother's day in my family always involves a bouquet of balloons.  Mom wanted to take the balloons we gave her home on the plane but in this hyper security aware atmosphere we doubted it was possible.

Getting them through security checkpoints would be a hassle at best.  As carry on's they'd fit overhead but likely wouldn't play well with other luggage.

We considered checking them but doubts ranged from air pressure changes to the baggage handler getting across the tarmac without accidently causing an air space violation.

The most practical solution is of course to just buy Mom more balloons when she returns home but Mom is sentimental.

Is there any guidance for this or was Mom crazy for even thinking we could do it?

Comment: Inflated I presume? I'd be worried about them bursting as cabin pressure drops, but I don't think there are any rules against it. Where are you trying to fly?

Comment: @CMaster Hmm well I had added a domestic tag to indicate this is not an international flight but mts removed it for some reason. It's about 5 hours in US airspace

Comment: loks like MTS removed the tag for those they felt were more relevant. Also, "Domestic" wouldn't tell me which country it was domestic within.

Comment: Would security allow, considering you can inflate the balloons with poisonous gases or something which might cause harm if it burst ?

Comment: @Dumbcoder How many poisonous gases are there that could cause harm with that limited volume that are also lighter than air?

Comment: Carbon Monoxide? Barley lighter than air mind, and probably only a threat if you had your head in the middle of the bouqet.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I removed the 'domestic-flight' tag as it does not carry any additional information, it refers to domestic as opposed to international flights. You probably mean domestic flight in the US and we currently don't have a proper tag for this afaik.

Comment: @mts should I add US to the title then rather than leave it buried in the comments?

Comment: @CandiedOrange don't worry too much about this. I wouldn't change the title as it's good already and more general than US is fine in this case but you could edit the text to make clear that in your particular case this is a US domestic flight.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34695/why-are-balloons-prohibited-at-amsterdam-schiphol

Comment: @JoErNanO I'd have to say related.  This is about planes not trains.  Planes already have problems with power lines without needing balloons to make it an issue.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Makes sense. Hence why I did not vote as duplicate. :)

Comment: Do we need a "Balloons" tag?

Comment: what a great question!  one issue is a balloon bouquet is *plain too big* on length/width for cabin baggage.  I'm very sure your Mom will understand that it would be impractical on an airplane (think og the hassles for her, too, even if "legal").

Comment: @JoeBlow, actually forget about _any_ hassle for the mom.  Think, and really focus on the hassle for everyone else involved.  From flight attendants to fellow passengers.  The key here is to think about others, not the balloons.

Comment: Note that the cabin and cargo hold on almost all planes are at the same pressure, so checked vs unchecked isn't an issue from a pressure point of view.

Comment: This is a must-do experiment: choose a seat in the back of the plane at online check-in, bring a helium balloon with you and release at when the plane starts to accelerate fast on the runway.

Comment: It might be wise to look at deflating the balloons - they can be kept as is for souvenirs (albeit ones that can be packed and stored more nicely), later mounted on paper or walls as flat decorations for display once home, or even (depending on deflation method) possibly re-inflated after traveling.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [TSA Can I Bring?](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?src=tsawebsite), impressively, has entries for both Balloons (inflated) and Balloon (uninflated).

For Balloon (inflated) it says:

> You may transport this items in carry-on or checked baggage. For items you wish to carry on, you should check with the airline to ensure that the item will fit in the overhead bin or underneath the seat of the airplane.

So airport security won't stop you. I can see the airline having some concerns however - one is that a bouqet of balloons is probably bigger than your carry-on allowance, especially if your mother is attempting to take carry on luggage as well. Of course, some airlines largley ignore these rules.

The other concern may be about the balloons popping and disrupting other passengers as the cabin pressure drops. You mention "lighter than air" in your question though, implying these are probably helium-filled balloons. If they are of the "foil" type, then I imagine those are a bit stronger. If plastic/latex, then the pressure change may just cause a faster leak rate than normal, rather than popping.

Anyway, it seems your mother shouldn't get in any trouble for trying it - just don't try it if someone at a later point asking to take them away will cause too much upset.

In the event that your mother does take the balloon onboard with her, and is unable/unwilling to stow them in the overhead lockers, [she should probably be aware of the somewhat counterintuitive physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXpURFYgR2E) of lighter-than-air objects in a moving vehicle, when attempting to keep control of them.

Comment: What do the EU regulations say about balloons? Let's make this a general question to avoid near-duplicates asking about other non-US flights.